# Azure storage defender

Tags: security, azure-storage, anonymous

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/alerts-reference#alerts-azurestorage
I see that storage accounts have "Anonymous access to a storage account " by default enabled. I am wondering which policy or mechanism triggers this? In azure defender i see that only policy mapping to this was "Azure Defender for Storage should be enabled". But i assumed this was just a audit check on enabled or disabled. I assumed it wont be doing all the listed alerts check. If it does, how is it being done? Does a blob or something store access logs which will trigger these? On VM i know it could be an agent etc, how is it done on storage.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, [Azure Defender for Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/azure-defender-storage-configure?tabs=azure-portal) offers the ability to detect [malware upon uploading files to a storage account using hash reputation analysis](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-security-center/validating-atp-for-azure-storage-detections-in-azure-security/ba-p/1068131) leveraging the power of Microsoft Threat Intelligence, which includes hashes for Viruses, Trojans, Spyware and Ransomware

We examine the storage logs and compare the hashes of newly uploaded files with those of known viruses, trojans, spyware, and ransomware. When a file is suspected to contain malware, Security Center displays an alert and can optionally email the storage owner for approval to delete the suspicious file.

1. Azure Defender for storage is based on the analysis of Azure Storage telemetry. This also applies to hash reputation analysis, but the coverage here is partial. When blobs or files are written, they may be accompanied by a hash of the blob of file that can be used for reputation analysis. This isn’t always the case however, and sometimes we don’t have a hash available, for example when files are written to with SMB.
2. As you may understand from the above, this is not a scanning process, so there is no audit either.

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.

Comment: My concern is that do still need to enable anonymous access diagnostic at storage account level or Defender takes care of it?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-prevent